# MongoError: "Unrecognized expression '$replaceAll'"

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, robo3t

I tried to run the following code in Mongodb (Version 4.4.5).

```
db.getCollection('articles').aggregate([
    { 
        $match: {
            'art_xml_data.article.journal_id': 'ei', 
            'art_status': 'publish'
        } 
    },
    {
         $addFields: { 
             test: { $replaceAll: { input: '$art_file_path', find: "/", replacement: "_" } } 
         } 
    },
    {
        $project: {
            'journal_id': '$art_xml_data.article.article_id',
            'file': '$art_file_path',
            'year': '$art_xml_data.article.pub_date.preprint.year',
            'gn': '$test'
        }
    }
])
```

But on executing it is showing,
***Error**: command failed: {
"ok" : 0,
**"errmsg" : "Unrecognized expression '$replaceAll'"**,
"code" : 168,
"codeName" : "InvalidPipelineOperator"
}*

I know $replaceOne and $replaceAll aggregation is introduced in Mongo version 4.4. Here my mongo version is 4.4.5 but still showing the error. Here is the version info:

```
MongoDB shell version v4.4.5
Build Info: {
    "version": "4.4.5",
    "gitVersion": "ff5cb77101b052fa02da43b8538093486cf9b3f7",
    "openSSLVersion": "OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020",
    "modules": [],
    "allocator": "tcmalloc",
    "environment": {
        "distmod": "ubuntu2004",
        "distarch": "x86_64",
        "target_arch": "x86_64"
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe check what the server output from: db.adminCommand( 
    { 
        getParameter: 1, 
        featureCompatibilityVersion: 1 
    } 
)

Comment: @R2D2 this is the output: {
    "featureCompatibilityVersion" : {
        "version" : "4.2"
    },
    "ok" : 1.0
}

Comment: Also db.version() ?

Comment: If your server is 4.4 , you can switch to 4.4 via : db.adminCommand( {
   setFeatureCompatibilityVersion: <version>,
   writeConcern: { wtimeout: <timeout> }
} )

Comment: Otherways you will need to upgrade 4.2 to 4.4 ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   db.adminCommand( { setFeatureCompatibilityVersion: "4.4", writeConcern: { wtimeout: 5000 } } )
```

must solve the problem if your binary is 4.4